# How can i integrate Facebook api in any android application?

Tags: android, facebook

What's the procedure to run Facebook Connect application in android? Here is the link:http://code.google.com/p/fbconnect-android/

Please explain step by step. I'm having errors in my manifest file:

```
<activity android:name="com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBLoginActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
        <activity android:name="com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBPermissionActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
        <activity android:name="com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBFeedActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
```

Comment: You need to be mention what errors you're having.  Though I imagine you're not seeing those activities resolve because you're not compiling against the JAR properly.  The website shows you how to add the JAR to your build path.

Answer (score 1):

Don't integrate Facebook API from mobile.

Instead you should create your own web service and put somewhere on the web where you can update API changes more frequently than rolling out new mobile version of your app for each API changes. So the point here is that you keep API calls on the webserver where you can do immediate changes rather than pushing mobile updates through time consuming Markets approval.

Make that go (1) Android phone -> (2) your webserver file with Facebook API --> (3) Facebook Servers.
You can find more examples working with Facebook API such as using PHP.